# IRenderFactory help in Minecraft Forge

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I've been having trouble with the new syntax for entity registry, specifically rendering the entity. Before, you simply added the `RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler` line to your `ClientProxy`, and that was that. But now, it's asking me to use `RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler` in the `preInit` along with a parameter called `IRenderFactory`. I'm not really sure how `IRenderFactory` works, or how I can create one (if I need to).

I've been told that you can use a method reference to pass your Render class's constructor (`RenderMyEntity::new`) as an `IRenderFactory` instead, but I really don't know how to go about this. I've done all kinds of research, but none of it makes sense.

Here's my `MobExample` class (the line `RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler(RenderGelZombie.class, renderFactory)` only works in the `preInit` of `MobExample` class, which is why it's there and not in `ClientProxy`):

```
package com.aideux.mobexample;

import com.aideux.basemod.BaseMod;

import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelZombie;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.RenderingRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.EntityRegistry;

public class MobExample 
{
public static int currentEntityId = 0;

public static void preInit()
{
    createEntityWithEgg(EntityGelZombie.class, "CustomMob", 0x00FF00, 0xFF0000);
    RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler(RenderGelZombie.class, renderFactory);
}

public static void init()
{
    BaseMod.proxy.registerEntityRenderers();
}

public static void createEntityWithEgg(Class entityClass, String entityName, int solidColor, int spotColor)
{
    int entityId = currentEntityId++;
    EntityRegistry.registerModEntity(entityClass, entityName, entityId, BaseMod.instance, 250, 1, true, solidColor, spotColor);
}
}
```

Comment: Google says it's an interface to return a `RenderEntity` instance. Do you have such a thing somewhere?

Comment: @zapl see, I don't really use Java that much, so I don't know what an interface is or how to return a render entity instance. Do you maybe know?

Comment: => https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html (or see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info for other resources). I know what interfaces are and how to return things, I'm not a modder so I have no clue what a `RenderEntity` is. But teaching the language basics is mostly off-topic here or already answered in detail.

Comment: @zapl could you perhaps quickly explain what they are and how to create/return them, and maybe I can try to figure it out? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `IRenderingFactory` interface in Forge creates instances of the Render class for your Entity. The docs that zapl linked above explain more about what an interface is as a concept.

In this case, you've got a class called `RenderGelZombie` that handles actually rendering your zombie in the game. Forge used to use this class directly when registering renderers, but now it uses `IRenderingFactory` to make instances of the render class. You'll need a factory class like this:

```
public class RenderGelZombieFactory implements IRenderFactory<EntityLiving> {

    public static final RenderGelZombieFactory INSTANCE = new RenderGelZombieFactory();

    @Override
    public Render<? super EntityLiving> createRenderFor(RenderManager manager) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new RenderGelZombie(manager, new ModelBiped(1.0f), 1.0f);
    }

}
```

Now that you've got a class that implements the IRenderFactory, you can pass it to the new entity rendering registry method:

```
RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler(EntityGelZombie.class, RenderGelZombieFactory.INSTANCE);
```

Source: I'm the curriculum developer for the iD Tech Camps Minecraft Modding course, and it looks like some of your code might have come from there!